# Two forms of a copy function in javascript

Tags: javascript, pointers, reference

There are usually two ways to copy an object. For example, using the C model, one way is you'd pass back a new object, and the second way is you'd write data to an existing object/address. Here are two ways to simulate doing that in JS:

```
function copy_array(arr) {
    // copy array and return existing array
    const cp = [];
    for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
        cp[i] = arr[i];
    return cp;
}
function copy_to(arr, to_arr) {
    // copy to existing object
    // possible to write to a "reference object", something like `&to_arr`
    to_arr = []
    for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
        to_arr[i] = arr[i];
    return to_arr;
```

```
const c = ['a','b','c'];
let arrc=copy_array(c);
const x=[];
copy_to(c, x);
```

Is it possible to copy objects these two ways? Or is copying to a reference object/address not possible?

Comment: Your `copy_to` function is flawed, it removes the reference to `to_arr` when you say `to_arr = []`

Comment: Arrays are objects.

Comment: ^^ and objects are reference types..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an object you do it essentially the same way, except you use `for (key in object)` to iterate over the property names.

```
function copy_to(obj, to_obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    to_obj[key] = obj[key];
  }
  return to_obj;
}
```

Comment: Though depending on whether you want all properties in the prototype chain or not you may want an `hasOwnProperty` check, or iterate `Object.keys(obj)`

Comment: Or maybe just do `Object.assign(to_obj, obj)`

Comment: @Keith I think the answer is in the spirit of hewing to the OPs function format.

Comment: @barmar -- wouldn't we need to empty the array before copying it over though? For example doing `to_obj.length=0;` ?

Comment: Objects don't have a `length` property. So this actually merges the objects, It's like `Object.assign(to_obj, obj)`

Comment: There's no simple way to empty an object. You need to loop over all its properties and delete them.